# Where is sample Firebird database?

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am using the FireDac Getting Starting demo for Firebird in Delphi Pro Tokyo 10.2 and cannot find the sample Firebird database. Does anyone know where I can find or download it?

Comment: [Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Data/). But I believe it should be part of examples in your setup.

Comment: @Victoria, yes it should be.  Mine is in Samples\Data in my Seattle setup but not, curiously in my Tokyo one, so maybe the sample dbs are not installed by default in Tokyo or I'm looking in the wrong place.  Maybe that's what prompted the Op's q.

Comment: @MartynA, it's a waaay long time I've installed samples :)

Comment: Victoria. It's not in my sample directory or in the one you provided the link for.  Also don't understand why this was voted down.  It's a legitimate question.

Comment: I have Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and the databases are located in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\Data

Comment: Do you specifically have the Firebird database.  I have Seattle, Berlin and Tokyo installed.  None have the Firebird database in the \Samples\Data folder for their specific installations.